# For covariant tensors, why is it $\bigwedge^k(V)$, not $\bigwedge^k(V^*)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

In learning the very basics of differential geometry, I have seen the exterior product defined a couple of ways: First, I have seen it as the image of the covariant tensors (which I believe are essentially the $k$-fold tensor product of $V^*$ with itself) transformed by the mapping "Alt". Second, I have seen it defined somewhat more abstractly as the $k$-fold tensor product of $V$ with itself, modulo certain relations which make it anti-symmetric. (However, at this early stage it seems we have no need for contravariant tensors.) In either case, we write it $\bigwedge^k(V)$. Since we are focusing on covariant tensors, why do we not write $\bigwedge^k(V^*)$? Is there something I am missing which makes these two equivalent?

Comment: Somewhere in there I believe a dual is lost. Your last hunch is absitively correct. Covariant tensors (for a manifold we take $V=TM$) are sections of $\otimes^*(V^*)$, and contravariant are sections of $\otimes^*(V)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right: this is a notation failure (on the part of many differential geometry texts).  The correct notation should be $\bigwedge^k (V^*)$, as you say.  However, confusingly many texts *write* $\bigwedge^k(V)$ to *mean* $\bigwedge^k(V^*)$.

(edit by EA, 5:54. fixed a typo)

Comment: The last two expressions look the same to me.

Comment: Thank you! It is relieving to know that I'm thinking along the right lines. Jesse, I tried to fix your typo, since it was clear what you meant, but it wouldn't let me, since I only added two characters.

Comment: I have to confess, I've contributed to propagating this notation failure.  I originally learned this stuff from Spivak (who used $\Omega^k(V)$ for the space of alternating covariant $k$-tensors on $V$) and later from Boothby (who used $\bigwedge^k(V)$), and in the first edition of my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_ I followed this trend with $\Lambda^k(V)$.  I've corrected the problem in the second edition, where I use $\Lambda^k(V^*)$ for the space of covariant alternating $k$-tensors and $\Lambda^k(V)$ for the contravariant ones.

Comment: @JackLee, I am reading and enjoying your book this summer!

Comment: @EricAuld, Thanks!  Hope you have the second edition! :-)

Comment: @JackLee Just bought the second edition, and I am very excited to read it (didn't get as much done over the summer as I'd have liked). I'm going to use it as a reference for the year-long Diff Geo course I'm taking.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why there should be a dual there is this: A covariant $r$ - tensor is by definition a multilinear map from $r$ copies $V \times \ldots \ldots \times V$ to the real numbers. We usually identify
$$\operatorname{Mult}(V \times \ldots \times V,\Bbb{R}) \cong V^\ast \otimes \ldots \otimes V^\ast$$

via the map that sends an elementary tensor $\varphi_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes \varphi_r$ on the R.H.S. to the multilinear map defined by

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \varphi_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes \varphi_r : &V \times \ldots \times V& \to \Bbb{R} \\
&(v_1,\ldots,v_r)& \mapsto \varphi_1(v)\ldots \varphi_r(v_r)\end{eqnarray*}$$

The last expression on the right is multiplication of real numbers. Thus in a similar way, we identify

$$\operatorname{Alt}(V \times \ldots \times V,\Bbb{R}) \cong V^\ast \wedge \ldots \wedge V^\ast.$$

Remember: A covariant tensor has to eat some bunch of vectors and spit out a real number, so any sensible definition involving these should involve the dual!